# 2016 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2016 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

> Please visit the official election page at
>
> https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Can we only nominate ourselves?  What if I would like to nominate someone else?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain This is how it works. You can only nominate yourself. If you want someone else to be a moderator, just convince him/her to nominate him/her self. If that specific someone does not want to be a moderator you cannot do much about it. You can write a meta post and if the post gets a lot of upvotes maybe you can convince that someone to nominate him/her self.

Comment: Too late, I nominated the two obvious candidates before realizing that _nominate_ has been commandeered to mean _volunteer_ here. Would be interesting to take this up at English SE.
True, though, that nobody should be nominated without having a solid reason to think that they would be willing to serve.

Comment: Ooops. guess I didn't nominate anyone, just put up what amount to a couple of campaign posters

Comment: How does this work?? For example, say the nomination phase is over, then what?? We vote?? How do we do that??

Comment: @Sid did you not read the post: "Please visit the official election page at http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/election for more detail, and to participate!"